# "Webhook Error: stripe.webhooks.constructEvent is not a function" using the example provided by Stripe docs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am following Stripe steps to integrate my endpoint to listen to Stripe events using webhooks.
If you go in their dashboard to `Developer>Webhooks>Add an endpoint>Test in a local environment`

In the page titled "Listen to Stripe events" They provide this sample Node js endpoint:

```
// server.js
//
// Use this sample code to handle webhook events in your integration.
//
// 1) Paste this code into a new file (server.js)
//
// 2) Install dependencies
//   npm install stripe
//   npm install express
//
// 3) Run the server on http://localhost:4242
//   node server.js

const stripe = require('stripe');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
const endpointSecret = "xxxxxxxxx";

app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
      const invoicePaymentSucceeded = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the event invoice.payment_succeeded
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

I keep getting the error:
`Webhook Error: Stripe.webhooks.constructEvent is not a function` in the try/catch.

- I have installed the packages: stripe and express using `npm install`
- When I type `stripe` it immediately shows me the available objects and functions including `webhooks.constructEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code provided you've simply imported the library. You haven't initialised a Stripe client by passing your secret API key. You need to initialise a client by either:

- Updating the line where you require `stripe`:

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')(YOUR_API_KEY)
```

- Initialise the client separately:

```js
const Stripe = require('stripe')

const stripe = new Stripe(YOUR_API_KEY)
```

See the `stripe-node` documentation for examples ([1](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/5a3ef258ecd1db0dce4eb44796036bff4dd835c9/examples/webhook-signing/express/main.ts#L10-L12), [2](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage)).

Comment: I see that you work at Stripe. It would be great if Stripe update the "sample endpoint" code to include the initialization of Stripe client.

Comment: Which sample/documentation are you referring to? Can you share a link?

Comment: Go to: https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks/create?endpoint_location=local
Then choose Node js in the top right dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **construct** `Stripe` client instance before using API.

```
const Stripe = require('stripe'); // <-- this is constructor

const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...'); // <-- this is a new client you can use later


...
let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent() // Notice small "s"
```