# How to use prebuilt Stripe Library to parse and manipulate incoming webhooks without API key

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using google cloud functions to create a webhook endpoint for Stripe (the payment processor).  I am using javascript(Node) and want to use Stripe's library to use commands like `let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);`.  Currently however, I cannot figure out how to make the `stripe` object without using an API key(e.g. `const stripe = require(‘stripe’)(functions.config().keys.my_api_key);`).

My thinking is that creating an unnecessary API key is a security vulnerability and that an API key is unnecessary for my purposes because I simply want to use the library to parse the incoming webhooks, extract the data, and store the extracted data to my firebase realtime database of customers, therefore i should never need to read or write any data in my stripe account using any API key.

Help appreciated. thank you!

I tried reading online docs: ["Webhook Error: stripe.webhooks.constructEvent is not a function" using the example provided by Stripe docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520423/webhook-error-stripe-webhooks-constructevent-is-not-a-function-using-the-exam)
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/5a3ef258ecd1db0dce4eb44796036bff4dd835c9/examples/webhook-signing/express/main.ts#L10-L12
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart?lang=node
https://paymentsplugin.com/blog/stripe-api-keys
https://medium.com/@GaryHarrower/working-with-stripe-webhooks-firebase-cloud-functions-5366c206c6c
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node
and much more.

Comment: If you do not wish to perform signature validation, you can simply take the event from request body. For example, `const event = request.body;`